# Jquery Validation First name and full name in one form

Tags: php, jquery, validation

There is one form (userFullname) in Registration fields.

Some user Typing only first name and i want to type also last names.

I want to type one word + second word space in the middle

help me

```
$("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            userfullname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
            /// I WANT SOME CODE THERE ///
            },
```

Comment: Rewrite your question, I can not understand

Comment: i think he means, he wants to make sure the user types both a first name and last name...

Comment: Yes. sorry for my eng

Comment: you need to add regex.

Comment: assuming my above comment is correct, the  basic idea is you have two text boxes (1 for first name, 1 for last name), and say a submit button (to submit). When you click the submit button, check the two text boxes to make sure they have text in them

Comment: @sagar as to my understanding, regex will check if a string has certain characters.... He wants to make sure the user is typing both a first and last name. While regex would be good to make sure users aren't typing numbers or symbols, I don't think it will work for the core of what he is trying to do...

Comment: He is trying to detect a string which must contain a space in between it. Like `sagar (space) Patro`. He does not want to allow `sagarpatro(withoutspace)`.

Comment: Finally i figured the regex. Please try

Answer (score -1):

I am just adding regex. It's upto you to complete.

```
$("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            userfullname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
            /// I WANT SOME CODE THERE ///
            regex: ^([a-zA-z])+(\s)+[a-zA-z]+$ //code added

            },
```